# Quasiconvexity via dominated convergence theorem in Dacorogna

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am reading the proof of the Dacorogna formula for quasiconvex envelop on page 271 of the book *Direct methods in the calculus of variations* by Dacorogna (Theorem 6.9).

In the beginning of step 3 of the proof. We have already established
$$\int_DQ'f(\xi+\nabla\psi(x))dx\geq Q'f(\xi)\cdot\textrm{meas}D$$
for all $\xi\in\mathbb R^{N\times n}$ and $\psi\in\mathcal A(D)$, where $\mathcal A(D)$ is the set
$$\mathcal A(D)=\{\varphi\in W^{1,\infty}_0(D;\mathbb R^N)\cap\textrm{Aff}_{piec}(\overline D;\mathbb R^N):\textrm{supp }\varphi\subseteq D\}$$
The author then claims that the continuity of $Q'f$ and the fact that $\mathcal A(D)$ is dense in $W^{1,\infty}_0$ in any $W^{1,p}$ norm, $1\leq p<\infty$, implies the quasiconvexity of $Q'f$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Now, given $\psi\in W^{1,\infty}_0$, we can find a sequence $\psi_n$ converging to $\psi$ in any $W^{1,p}$ norm. However, I don't see why this should imply $\nabla \psi_n$ converges to $\nabla\psi$ pointwise which is what I think we would need to apply the dominated convergence theorem. Also would the dominating function be $f$? We already know that $f\geq Q'f$ and $f$ is bounded on compact sets, but I'm not sure how to handle the possible domain difference for $f$ and $Q'f(\xi+\nabla\psi(x))$. I am not very fluent in Sobolev space theory. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest that you recall the definition of $Q'f$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you already know, at Step 3, that for all $\xi\in\mathbb R^{N\times n}$ and $\psi\in\mathcal A(D)$
$$\int_DQ'f(\xi+\nabla\psi(x))dx\geq Q'f(\xi)\cdot\textrm{meas}D$$

Which is almost quasiconvexity of $f$: you only need to go from the condition for all $\psi\in\mathcal A(D)$ to the condition for all $\psi\in W_0^{1, \infty}(D ; \mathbb{R}^n).$ Since $\mathcal A(D)$ is dense in $W_0^{1, \infty}(D ; \mathbb{R}^n)$, then, by continuity, the following quantities are the same (to see this, just recall that the infimum is just a limit and taking a limit of a continuous function on a dense set of $X$ is the same as taking it on all $X$):

$$\tilde{Q} f(\xi):=\inf \left\{\frac{1}{\text { meas } D} \int_{D} f(\xi+\nabla \varphi(x)) d x: \varphi \in W_{0}^{1, \infty}\left(D ; \mathbb{R}^{N}\right)\right\}$$ and $$ Q^{\prime} f(\xi):=\inf \left\{\frac{1}{\text { meas } D} \int_{D} f(\xi+\nabla \varphi(x)) d x: \varphi \in \mathcal{A}(D)\right\}$$

But now, the quantity $Q'f$ is under the integral, hence to be able to "take the limit", you need to appeal to a convergence theorem: the easiest is the Lebesgue one. Hence, by density you have $\psi_n \rightarrow \psi$ is Sobolev norm, hence you have convergence in $L^p$ of the gradients as well. From them, you can extract a subsequence converging pointwise *almost everywhere* (which is all that you need to apply Lebesgue dom. conv. thm, since your measure space is complete: see [Remark 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)). The domination comes from the fact that for all $\xi\in\mathbb R^{N\times n}$ you have that $Q'f$ is an infumum of a bounded quantity since $f$ is locally bounded: note that since you are converging to $\tilde{Q} f(\xi)$, which is an inf on a bigger set, then your sequence is decreasing. Hence its enough to take $Q'f$ as dominated function, which is bounded on $D$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that given $\psi\in W^{1,\infty}_0(D;\mathbb{R}^N)$, we can find a sequence $\psi_n$ such that $\nabla\psi_n\to\nabla\psi$ a.e. pointwise. But I am still unsure about the dominating function part. Do you mean that $Q'f(\xi+\nabla\psi_n(x))dx\leq Q'f(x)$ or $Q'f(\xi+\nabla\psi_n(x))dx\leq f(x)$?

Comment: First: yes. Second: neither of the two, since you just dominate $Q’f$ for any value of $\xi$. So just call $\eta := \xi \nabla \psi_n$, which is still a vector and you are fine

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with $\eta$. We know that given $x_0\in D$, we have $Q'f(\xi+\nabla\psi_n(x_0))\leq\frac1{\textrm{meas} D}\int_DQ'f(\xi+\nabla\psi_n(x_0)+\varphi(x))dx$ for any $\varphi\in\mathcal A(D)$, but how do we get rid of the dependence on $n$, and what should $\varphi$ be.